# Solve equation for x: $m^2(z^2-25)=n^2(z^2-25)$

Tags: quadratics

$$m^2(z^2-25)=n^2(z^2-25)$$

I don't get it? I don't even have x anywhere in this equation. Can somebody make this a bit clearer?

Comment: Perhaps one of the $z$s should be an $x$?

Comment: Where we need to see $x$?

Comment: Oh.. I guess the z is supposed to be x in this equation

Comment: Since it says m and n are parameters

Answer (score 1):

It's $$(m^2-n^2)(z^2-25)=0.$$

If $m^2=n^2$ we get $\mathbb R$.

If $m^2\neq n^2$ we get $z^2=25$, which gives $\{-5,5\}$.

Comment: That is indeed correct. I was confused as I didn't see any x's but the problem meant the z was x.

Comment: Yes! I understood this point.